# PHP generated html text box to calculate amt=qty* price

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

```
$res=mysql_query($qry);
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
echo "<tr><td>".$row['Food_Name']."</td>
<td>".$row['Price']."</td>
<td><input type='text' name='qty". $row['code']."[]' size='2'/></td>                               
<td><input type='text' name='amt". $row['code']."[]'  size='2'/></td>    
     </tr> 
}
```

[image: This is the Output of the php code]

I have write this code to display the food_name and price, and display two textboxes for qty and amt.
Now I need to calculate price*qty and display the result in amt box.

please help., javascript, php, ajax, jquery anything only the result should appear. The table is displaing on a popupoverlay jquery.

```
<tr>
<td>Mutton Kasha</td>
<td>250</td>
<td><input type='text' name='qtySPJ1[]' size='2'/></td>                            
<td><input type='text' name='amtSPJ1[]'  size='2'/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Mutton Butter Masala</td>
<td>850</td>
<td><input type='text' name='qtySPJ1[]' size='2'/></td>                            
<td><input type='text' name='amtSPJ1[]'  size='2'/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Firstly, show what you have tried so far. Second, please show the output HTML (e.g. saved from your browser) for questions like this. It saves us mentally compiling PHP :)

Comment: You need to try something. People aren't here to do your work for you

Comment: Advice: Listen for `change` events on the inputs. Then, per row, calculate the prices. I think you will find you do need *the code* :) You could at least provide the output page HTML requested... more chance of help then :)

Comment: A screen shot, while pretty, is *not* as useful as the HTML from the page!

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie   what happend to u guys? So silent.

Comment: @chaliefl  what happend to u guys? So silent.

Comment: I was busy coding (most of us also have real jobs) :) I added an example based on your mockup. I added a few classes to make the selection easier as `[]` in names makes it more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a basic idea of what you can do:

```
$('input.qty').change(function(){
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var price = parseFloat($tr.find('td').eq(1).text());
    var amt = parseInt($(this).val());
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input.amt').val(amt * price);
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/hfakf6zr/1/

This listens for changes to inputs with class="qty" and updates the amount accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy. You can do something like this:
**PHP Code**

```
$res=mysql_query($qry);
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['Food_Name']."</td>
        <td class=\"price\">".$row['Price']."</td>
        <td><input type='text' class=\"qty\" name='qty". $row['code']."[]' size='2'/></td>                               
        <td><input type='text' class=\"amt\" name='amt". $row['code']."[]'  size='2'/></td>
    </tr> 
}
```

Now in your jQuery. Add this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var qty = $("input.qty"),
        price;
    qty.on("input", function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        price = +($this.closest("td").siblings("td.price").text());
        $this.closest("td").siblings("td.amt").val(price*(+$this.val()));
    });
});
```

You can also use other events such as Blur. Hope that works :)

Comment: No problem @SouravSarkar. I'm glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function multiply() {
   var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
   var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
   if (txtFirstNumberValue == "")
       txtFirstNumberValue = 0;
   if (txtSecondNumberValue == "")
       txtSecondNumberValue = 0;

   var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) * parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
   if (!isNaN(result)) {
       document.getElementById('txt3').value = result;
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but I have two questions 1. where should I call the function may be onchange().2 I am using textbox array and php variable not txt1,and txt2. Please read my code.